# how to restrict posts_request filter to the main query only

Tags: pre-get-posts

I'm trying to run custom sql for search results, and I'm having trouble limiting the filter to the main query without running a redundant query.

I'm successfully getting results via the following:

```
add_filter( 'posts_request', 'my_request_filter' );

function my_request_filter($sql) {
    if(is_search()) {
        $sql = 'some custom sql query'
    }
    return $sql;
}
```

The problem here is that this is affecting other things on the page running queries, like the recent posts widget.  I can prevent this by adding 'suppress_filters' => true to the other queries, but that seems a bit backwards, and I'm not going to hack core to add that.

the 'pre_get_posts' filter seems more appropriate, in that I can check for is_main_query, but I'm limited in how I can modify the query with this filter - I can't figure out how to entirely replace the query object with one created by a custom sql statement.

The least ideal solution would be to simply ignore the main query, and run another one entirely; but the whole point of this exercise was to replace the main query with one optimized for this context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The posts_request filter actually takes a second argument, which is the query. You can check if that query is the main query. Try this:

```
add_filter( 'posts_request', 'my_request_filter', 10, 2 );

function my_request_filter($sql, $query) {
    if($query->is_main_query() && is_search()) {
        $sql = 'some custom sql query'
    }
    return $sql;
}
```